"horizontal sum" in DuckDB?
In Polars I can do:
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
df.select(pl.sum_horizontal('a', 'b'))

shape: (3, 1)
┌─────┐
│ a   │
│ --- │
│ i64 │
╞═════╡
│ 5   │
│ 7   │
│ 9   │
└─────┘

Is there a way to do this with DuckDB?

Isn't it just select a + b - or am I misunderstanding?

right, i can just do rel.select('+'.join(rel.columns)). that was easy. thanks!

I was looking for solution to sum any number of columns and completely missed that there're only 2 in the actual question.

COLUMNS() can now be unpacked as of DuckDB 1.1.0
This does allow you to use the list_* functions e.g.
duckdb.sql("""
from df 
select list_sum(list_value(*columns(*)))
""")

┌──────────────────────────────────┐
│ list_sum(list_value(df.a, df.b)) │
│              int128              │
├──────────────────────────────────┤
│                                5 │
│                                7 │
│                                9 │
└──────────────────────────────────┘


wow, this is amazing!

If one wants to avoid explicitly specifying the columns,
then assuming all the columns in table t are integers, you can use the following technique, provided the JSON extension has been loaded, as by:
load JSON;

select list_sum(list_transform( json_keys(j), 
  k -> json_extract(j,k)::INTEGER)) as sum 
from (select t::json j from t);

With a bit of work, the assumptions can be weakened,
e.g. non-integer values could be replaced by 0;
or one could use the EXCLUDE feature to exclude certain columns, as by:
select u::json j from (select * exclude(x) from t) as u;

Example:
from t;
┌───────┬───────┐
│   a   │   b   │
│ int32 │ int32 │
├───────┼───────┤
│     1 │     4 │
│     2 │     5 │
│     3 │     6 │
└───────┴───────┘

Output from the query shown above:
┌────────┐
│  sum   │
│ int128 │
├────────┤
│      5 │
│      7 │
│      9 │
└────────┘

